# Why this echo construct does not work?

Tags: bash, echo

When I do this:

```
$ /bin/echo 123 | /bin/echo
```

I get no o/p. Why is that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You ask why it doesn't work.  In fact, it does work; it does exactly what you told it to do.  Apparently that's not what you expected.  I think you expected it to print `123`, but you didn't actually say so.

(Note: "stdin" is standard input; "stdout" is standard output.)

`/bin/echo 123 | /bin/echo`

Here's what happens.  The `echo` command is executed with the argument `123`.  It writes "123", followed by a newline, to its stdout.

stdout is redirected, via the pipe (`|`) to the stdin of the second `echo` command.  Since the echo command ignores its stdin, the output of the first echo is quietly discarded.  Since you didn't give the second echo command any arguments, it doesn't print anything.  (Actually, /bin/echo with no arguments typically prints a single blank line; did you see that?)

Normally pipes (`|`) are used with *filters*, programs that read from stdin and write to stdout.  `cat` is probably the simplest filter; it just reads its input and writes it, unchanged, to its output (which means that `some-command | cat` can be written as just `some-command`).

An example of a non-trivial filter is `rev`, which copies stdin to stdout while reversing the characters in each line.

```
echo 123 | rev
```

prints

```
321
```

`rev` is a filter; `echo` is not.  `echo` does print to stdout, so it makes sense to have it on the left side of a pipe, but it doesn't read from stdin, so it doesn't make sense to use it on the right side of a pipe.

Comment: Thanks. The answer is "echo ignores stdin"!

Answer (score 5):

"echo" reads from command line, not standard input. So pipeline is not working here.

From bash manual:

```
echo [-neE] [arg ...]

Output the args, separated by spaces, terminated with a newline.
```

So your first echo did print "123" to stand output, however, the second echo didn't make use of it so "123" is dropped. Then an empty line is printed as if you run "echo".

You can use cat as Keith Thompson suggested:

```
echo 123|cat
```

Comment: Right.  Try `/bin/echo 123 | /bin/cat`.  (Of course a simple `echo 123` does the same thing.)

Comment: exactly. cat is what he needs.

Comment: Thanks, but my question is not how to print characters to screen. It is why the echo construct I was trying does not work. There is a huge difference.

Comment: As I said, the output of the first echo is not used. So your command is the same as running "echo" only. Remember that echo doesn't reads from standard input at all.

Comment: @qiaomuf: It depends on what he's trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
/bin/echo 123 < /bin/echo
```

<strike>the pipe = concate</strike>

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-4.html

> Pipes let you use the output of a program as the input of another one

Comment: "the pipe = concate"? Even without the typo this seems like a confusing kind of explanation

Comment: Thanks. But I thought, with what I had, first echo would redirect its o/p to pipe and second one would get its i/p from the pipe. Is that not right?

Comment: Yes I did not get the pipe=concate part either. What does that mean?

Comment: @sehe I would love to hear your explanation too.

Comment: `/bin/echo 123 < /bin/echo` is a very odd thing to do.  It runs `/bin/echo`, which ignores standard input, with its input redirected from the `/bin/echo` executable file.  The command could even fail if `/bin/echo` is executable but not readable.

Comment: -1 This does not answer the question or explain the concepts.